# Amazon and multi customer support in shared multi-tenant model

Tags: amazon-web-services, multi-tenant

Are there any ready services (by amazon or partners) that help you manage multi-customer aspects of a "pool" [1][2] type service - where all the multi-tenancy is handled by internal context switching, databases are shared, etc.

AWS tools (marketplace, billing manager) seems to be geared toward "provision new service / host by customer" while what I'm looking for is the customer and license management, user association, authentication (including federated authentication integration with multiple customer portals) and perhaps even listing and catalog services - but when a new customer purchase (or change) a license / user / configuration - I expect to get an API call to my already existing solution - in which I'll decide what to do.

Seems like there should be many services like that - but either they are proprietary, or I'm using the wrong keywords to find the information.

[1] http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/arc340-multitenant-application-deployment-models/9

[2] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMP0leGZpo4

Comment: There is really not enough information here to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: @chris - part of the problem is that I don't have enough information myself. However, I'm can't find any hints around to web to leverage myself to the next level of understanding - which is why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the results from my own research on the subject:

There are two identity management type solutions - one that acts as a portal for the user, showing multiple applications, and the other that acts as a user database with login facilities. The first one was not applicable to my case so I didn't look at it. Some examples of the first type: Okta, SecureKey, OnCloud, Sailpoint.

Of the 2nd type, I looked at the following dimensions: Support for multiple federated Idps, support for SAML federation, Support for API control, UI dashboard (with note for per customer filtering), Support for active directory sync, Support for SP multi tenancy, Support for home realm discovery, Certifications, Ability to embed the solution, Price.

My short list was Auth0, AWS cognito and Stormpath.

Auth0:

- Supports multiple federated Idps with multiple technologies (SAML supported)
- Supports full API control
- Has UI dashboard, lacks per-customer filtering
- Support active directory sync using an agent
- Lacks SP multi-tenant support
- Can support MT by metadata on user (virtual separation)
- Lacks home realm discovery
- Can support HRD programmatically by holding a mapping table
- Has HIPPA (US gov health) certification
- Can be embedded within a solution or used as an online service
- High cost per month 1000$/2500 active federated users per month at a plan lower than the one we needed

AWS Cognito:

- Supports multiple federated Idps through SAML
- Supports full API control (? TBD verify)
- Has UI dashboard, supports per customer filtering
- Doesn’t support active directory sync
- Limited to 60 customers (user pools)

  - Need to be negotiated with Amazon
- Supports SP multi tenancy (user pool origin and metadata)
- Unknown home realm discovery - TBD

  - Currently available on US-East, Ireland and Tokyo
- If successful, most likely to be available in othe regions and gov-cloud in the future
- Low cost – per month 275$/50k monthly active users
  Note – our use case is not the primary use case for this service (may lead to dead ends)

Stormpath

- Supports multiple federated Idps using SAML
- Supports full API control (? TBD verify)
- Has UI dashboard, supports per customer filtering
- Support active directory sync using agent
- Lacks SP multi-tenant support

  - Can support MT by metadata on user (virtual separation)
- Lacks home realm discovery

  - Can support HRD programmatically by holding a mapping table
- Can be embedded within a solution or used as an online service
- Low cost – 500$/500k API calls per month for a package at a lower level than what we need

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is basically "what tools can I use to build a multi-tenant application".

And the answer will be "it depends".  You don't have enough requirements to determine what would be useful or helpful.

However, AWS does have some technologies that may help.  Start by looking at AWS Cognito.  It can do authentication and data access, and use federated authentication providers.  It also handles storing data for multiple users in DynamoDB.

If you're looking for anything more than that, however, you need to provide more information.

Can you shard MySQL across multiple RDS instances, and have one schema per client?  Sure, but that's probably not going to work well if you have a million clients - there are limits on the number of schemas per instance.

Same thing with S3 - you can have a bucket per client, or a subdirectory under a shared bucket per client, but I can't tell you which approach is going to work best for your application.

AWS has enough tools to automate the creation of a complete stack per customer - between the API/CLI, CloudFormation, etc - but unless you're dealing with a very high-value product, that's probably not going to be cost effective.

Comment: you're absolutely right. As I stated in the question, the basic assumption is "shared everything", so stack per customer is not an option. However, the question was not about deployment but actually about user and customer (tenant in my question) management and per customer federated login support (multiple login portals). Cognito may be able to support some of the needed features, but with a limit of 60 pools per account, doesn't really allow massive multi customer usage.

Comment: @RanBiron:  Most AWS limits can be increased.  You can ask for an increase in the number of pools per account, or users/clients per pool.